# How to make a Button change Background and Text color on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a button that changes the background colour of the entire page and some of the text colour but I can't make it work.

The background is working at the moment but the text doesn't change color. I want the "changeText" to affect Classes instead of Ids.

I have zero knowledge of JavaScript, so it's hard to know what's wrong.

This is the code:

```js
var colors = ["green", "red", "blue"];
var colorIndex = 0;

function changeText() {
  var col = document.getElementsByClassname("textcolor");
  if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
    colorIndex = 0;
  }
  col.body.style.color = colors[colorIndex];
  colorIndex++;
}

var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
var colorIndex = 0;

function changeBackground() {
  var col = document.getElementById("bodycolor");
  if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
    colorIndex = 0;
  }
  col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
  colorIndex++;
}
```

```html
<body id='bodycolor'>

  <h1 class="textcolor">Title Color Change</h1><br>
  <p class="textcolor">Text Color Change </p><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="changeBackground();changeText();">Click me</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Typo in `getElementsByClassname`. Should be `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: try replacing col.body.style.color = colors[colorIndex]; with col.style.color = colors[colorIndex]; + getElementsByClassName returns a collection so you will have to loop through them

Comment: You also don't need to declare `colors` and `colorIndex` before each function you can just declare them once at the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You background change works because getElementById returns just one element on which you can set the style properties.

getElementsByClassName() however return a collection of items. You will have to iterate over it and change the style element per element. Try this:

```
function changeText() {
  var col = document.getElementsByClassName("textcolor");
  if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
    colorIndex = 0;
  }
for(var i = 0; i < col.length; i++){
  col[i].style.color = colors[colorIndex];
}
  colorIndex++;
}
```

Also, you don't need the .body to set the style.

Comment: There is a slight typo in the answer, where defining 'col' there is a lower case 'n' on classname. Change this to capital. E.g. 'className'

Comment: Oh yeah, that's my bad! I put it like that in the initial code. Now it's working! Thank you so much guys :)

Comment: Just ran this and it works. Make sure that on top of this you don't forget to fix the typo as mentioned by @j08691 in a comment on your post.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName return array of all the elements containing mentioned classname

try

```
col[0].style.color = colors[colorIndex];
```

Here is an working sample for you

Visit https://codepen.io/vikas_saini/pen/jOOErNZ

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("textcolor")` is an array of elements. You need to loop through them and apply the color at `colors[colorIndex]` to them. This is achieved by the added for loop and by applying `colors[colorIndex]` to `col[i].style.color` where `i` is the index of the loop. `col[i]` is the element in the array at that index.

You also needed to move the conditional for `colorIndex` above the loop so as to adjust the index before you start applying the style. If `colorIndex` is 3, you need to change that back to 0 before you start applying the styles.

```html
<body id='bodycolor'>
<h1 class="textcolor">Title Color Change</h1><br>
<p class="textcolor">Text Color Change </p><br>



<button type="button" onclick="changeBackground();changeText();">Click me</button>



<script>

var colors = ["green", "red", "blue"];
    var colorIndex = 0;
    function changeText() {
        var col = document.getElementsByClassName ("textcolor");
      if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++){
          col[i].style.color = colors[colorIndex]
        } 
        colorIndex++;
    }

var colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
    var colorIndex = 0;
    function changeBackground() {
        var col = document.getElementById("bodycolor");
        if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
        colorIndex++;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give it Unique IDs and check it out

```
  let colors = ["green", "red", "blue"];
    let colorIndex = 0;

    function changeBackground() {
      let col = document.getElementById("bodycolor");
      if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
        colorIndex = 0;
      }
      col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
      colorIndex++;

       let h1Color = document.getElementById("h1Color")
       let pColor = document.getElementById("pColor");

      if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
        colorIndex = 0;
      }
      h1Color.style.color = colors[colorIndex];
      pColor.style.color = colors[colorIndex];
     colorIndex++;
    }
```

```html
 <body id='bodycolor'>
      <h1 id="h1Color">Title Color Change</h1><br>
      <p id="pColor">Text Color Change </p><br>
      <button type="button" onclick="changeBackground()">Click me</button>
    </body>
```